# What is the meaning of this Krishna mantra?

Tags: krishna, sanskrit

What is the meaning of this Krishna mantra -

कृष्णाय वासुदेवाय हरये परमात्मने। प्रणत क्लेशनाशाय गोविन्दाय नमो नम: